# How to implement similar line chart using the Highcharts library?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, data-visualization

I am trying to generate a following line chart using HighChart library using the same data as shown on the pic below. The challenge is that I am new to this and have no idea how to develop this in HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript. Can someone guide me or perhaps help me with this so I can see how it works?

[image: Line Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a similar chart in the demo below. I suggest starting from the official documentation. It's a rich library, and a lot of things can be set via API properties which you might check in the link below.
The most important part here is how you prepare the data.

```
series: [{
    name: 'NVDA',
    data: [30, 50, 40, 60],
    color:'blue'
  }
  ...
]
```

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/
**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highcharts
**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aj918gLt/

Comment: Thanks Karol, really appreciate your response and help. I was able to complete mine by going over a smilier example as yours and by following the documentation. Regardless, I appreciate the help.